A book about a kid who has a magic baseball glove
I'm looking for a story that matches this description:

A kid had a magic glove that could catch anything.
He traded it away so that he could make a tunnel under his baseball field, to prevent a road from being built through the field.
There was a magical creature who gave the kid the power to ask for what he wanted.
When the magical creature was helping to dig the tunnel (while all traffic stopped, the world was on pause), he didn’t have enough magic and the kid kept agreeing to give back some things, ending finally with his magic glove.
Then the creature finished the tunnel under the field, so the baseball field was saved.

More information about the book:

It was aimed at probably upper elementary/middle school.
It was not a picture book.
It was probably from the early 90s.


Welcome to Lit.SE. You've given a nice summary of the plot, but a few more details might be helpful. When did you read this book? What age-audience was it aimed at? Was it a picture book?

@CDR Thanks for the prompt! I've added some more information.

This appears to be The Three and Many Wishes of Jason Reid by Hazel Hutchins (1983).
To quote the description from Goodreads:

What would you do with three wishes? When eleven-year-old Jason Reid is offered three wishes from an Elster of the Third Order called Quicksilver, he starts off greedy and frivolous, and his third wish is always for three more. Soon Jason realizes that Quicksilver is fading from the strain and that he must let him go. But Jason makes his last wish count: he saves the local baseball field and surrounding park from destruction.

One of the reviews mentions the magical baseball glove (quoted exactly):

The elf told to Jason he had a power he can led him some wishes(only three), the fisrt wish are a pair of beisball gloves, for doing better the function of catching the ball.

What they have to save the baseball field from specifically isn't mentioned in the reviews or the description, but searching in Google Book's snippet view for the word "tunnel" does come up with the quote

'We want you to build a tunnel,' said Jason.


Identified by a Google search for "baseball glove" "magic" "tunnel" in the Books section of Google, filtered to show only results from the 20th century.
